# Execute stored procedure with spring

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

When I try to execute stored procedure with spring the this exception is thrown:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call TEST_PKG.DO_IT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [72000]; error code [1461]; ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
ORA-06512: at "TEST.TEST_PKG", line 53
ORA-06512: at line 1
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
ORA-06512: at "TEST.TEST_PKG", line 53
ORA-06512: at line 1

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:124)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:952)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:985)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:117)
```

I'm using myfaces 1.2.5, spring 2.0.2

The first argument is Integer and the last is NUMBER. The mapping of the Oracle Types and Java types are as follows:

```
Integer -> Numeric
NUMBER -> Decimal.
```

My question is what is the reason of this exception and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the new rows in text inserted in the DB. I just call replacaAll("\n","")
and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error originates from LINE 53 of TEST.TEST_PKG

There seems to be an INSERT statement with incorrect binding types.

Comment: The database developer already see that case and say that everything is ok in DB. The strange thing is that it work in Google Chrome but not in IE.